# Logic Analysis of a 8 bit mcu

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, sampling

I would like to sample the logic on the pins out out of a toy robot's processor and the MCU is an 8 bit processor that operates a max clock speed of 5 Mhz.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to approach this without burning it out, I have an oscilloscope but its only two channel.

[image]

[SPC252A Data Sheet](http://www.ic72.com/pdf_file/-/428527.pdf)

Comment: if you can sample fast enough you can use another mcu or processor to sample and store or sample and display.  build your own logic analyzer...

Comment: Google USB logic Analyser.  Shopping recommendations are off topic here but there are some relativity cheep ones if you don't need to sample particularly fast.

Comment: For about US$20, you can get a JTAG debugger that can read the pins (e.g. Adafruit #3517). I just ordered, from Amazon, a 9-bit logic analyzer (ASIN #B07F8C1PMQ, about US$9, haven’t received it yet.

Comment: How do you know that the chip even has a JTAG interface?

Comment: It's most likely that this is an MCU with all of the data lines and address lines inside of the MCU. If there is no external memory it is unlikely that you'll have access to anything interesting without accessing the die itself, especially if the other signals are GPIO's.

Comment: I think I have a solution here, I will use my MAX 10 FPGA Eval Board and attempt to capture logic using this. I think its the best solution atm.

Answer (score 1):

There is an equipment intended to use in this case. It is named **logic analyser**. There are plenty on the market. Stand alone ones, or PC-based. You may check the logic states of multiple pins (8, 16, 32 channels or more).
If you have only 2-channel oscilloscope you are still in a good situation. Tweak your code: select 'debug' pin and make it toggle when a particular thing should happen. Then, connect your probe to this pin and you can check for example: is microprocessor going into interrupt, into a loop, you can check some of execution time, etc. There is a lot of possibilities with it, all you need is to use your imagination and thinking.

Comment: I do know what a logic analyzer is, I was just trying to avoid spending $300 to $500 to capture so many channels. I think I am going to try to use my MAX 10 FPGA Eval Board here to hopefully do the job.

Comment: This microprocessor works with maximum of 5MHz clock. You don't have to spend this much. Here is something more affordable: http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Logic_Pirate